# Change regex pattern to match string one character at a time

Tags: c#, regex

I am making a regex pattern that matches decimal latitude and longitude for a certain area.  It should match from 40 to 46 OR 115 to 125, then a decimal, then up to 10 digits.  It does this.  The problem is it is being used for ASYNC validation, so each individual digit/character needs to match.  Here is the pattern:

```
@"^((4[0-6])|(11[5-9]|12[0-5]))(\.|°)?([0-9]{1,10})°?$";
```

So it should match 4, 43, 43., 43.123 etc.  It matches a a full pattern, but not individuals.  I have been looking into non-capturing groups, but it doesn't seem like it would fit here and my testing has not borne fruit. AM I on the wrong track?

Comment: Why should it match `4`? If the string is a sole `4` then you'd get a false match?

Comment: True.  Maybe I need a couple patterns in a switch statement, so the string can fall through until it either matches something or fails.

Comment: Regex seems ill-suited for this particular scenario. You could pull it off with a ton of nested, optional, non-capturing groups, but you'd wind up with a complete mess of an expression.

Comment: What about something like `^(?!.*°°.*$)(?:((4[0-6])|(11[5-9]|12[0-5]))(\.|°)?([0-9]{1,10})?°?|4|1[12]?)$` ? Demo: https://regex101.com/r/fL4aU3/1. Note you cannot use it for final validation.

Comment: I agree with Adrian, just parse it char by char. I'll be safer, easier and faster.

Comment: Regular expressions to only match a full pattern. You may use a state machine to track the state during processing, but a regular expression would not help you there except if you would have every async possibility as a separate regular expression (or "|" - or - them) which would result in too many parts/expressions.

Comment: I am now convinced that regex is not the way to go here. If someone wants to throw up an answer to that effect, I will close this thing up and we can get on with our days.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(((4[0-6])|(11[5-9]|12[0-5]))(\.|°)?([0-9]{1,10})°?(, )?)+
```

Does this expression fit your needs?

Answer (score 0):

I am now convinced that regex is not the way to go here. If someone wants to throw up an answer to that effect, I will close this thing up and we can get on with our days. Thank you. –  BattlFrog